# Unimplemented: graph execution error ; DNN library is not found (jupyter on windows)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have created a new environment in miniconda3 with all the latest updated libraries and followed the guidelines on the TensorFlow official page [https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip](https://stackoverflow.com)with all the recommended updated i.e. NVIDIA® GPU drivers version 450.80.02 or higher, CUDA® Toolkit 11.8 and cuDNN SDK 8.6.0. The Tensor Flow Version: 2.12.0 and
Keras Version: 2.12.0. while using this block of code, it seems that gpu is integrated well. However still I am getting  Unimplemented: graph execution error ; DNN library is not found

Can someone point out what is wrong with this code?

```
import sys

import tensorflow.keras
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
import tensorflow as tf

print(f"Tensor Flow Version: {tf.__version__}")
print(f"Keras Version: {tensorflow.keras.__version__}")
print()
print(f"Python {sys.version}")
print(f"Pandas {pd.__version__}")
print(f"Scikit-Learn {sk.__version__}")
gpu = len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))>0
print("GPU is", "available" if gpu else "NOT AVAILABLE")
```

it gives the output

```
Tensor Flow Version: 2.12.0
Keras Version: 2.12.0

Python 3.11.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Apr  6 2023, 08:57:19) [GCC 11.3.0]
Pandas 2.0.0
Scikit-Learn 1.2.2
GPU is available
```

I am trying to fit an efficienctnetB1 model for image classification purpose. But the model.fit is giving errors.

```
history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(train_generator.samples//train_generator.batch_size),
    batch_size=32,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=math.ceil(validation_generator.samples//validation_generator.batch_size),
    verbose=1,
    epochs=50,
    callbacks=[callbacks_list],
)
```

which gives the output as

```
Epoch 1/50
2023-04-23 14:21:57.503000: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_0' with dtype int32
     [[{{node Placeholder/_0}}]]
2023-04-23 14:22:10.285135: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:417] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.1.0 but source was compiled with: 8.6.0.  CuDNN library needs to have matching major version and equal or higher minor version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
2023-04-23 14:22:10.288074: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops.cc:1068 : UNIMPLEMENTED: DNN library is not found.
2023-04-23 14:22:10.288224: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): UNIMPLEMENTED: DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node model/efficientnetb1/stem_conv/Conv2D}}]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 history = model.fit(
      2     train_generator,
      3     steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(train_generator.samples//train_generator.batch_size),
      4     batch_size=32,
      5     validation_data=validation_generator,
      6     validation_steps=math.ceil(validation_generator.samples//validation_generator.batch_size),
      7     verbose=1,
      8     epochs=50,
      9     callbacks=[callbacks_list],
     10 )

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:

UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'model/efficientnetb1/stem_conv/Conv2D' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1043, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 725, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1922, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 513, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 502, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 729, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 422, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 540, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3006, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3061, in _run_cell
      result = runner(coro)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3266, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3445, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3505, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_730/4294235073.py", line 1, in <module>
      history = model.fit(
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 558, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1145, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 512, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 669, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 558, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1145, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 512, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 669, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1145, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 290, in call
      outputs = self.convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
    File "/home/rsharda/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 262, in convolution_op
      return tf.nn.convolution(
Node: 'model/efficientnetb1/stem_conv/Conv2D'
DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node model/efficientnetb1/stem_conv/Conv2D}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_22437]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you are trying to have GPU support with `TensorFlow 2.12` which is not supported. Please check the below comment in the same [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) mentioned by you.

> TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on
> native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to
> install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow or tensorflow-cpu
> and, optionally, try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin

Comment: ..thanks for the suggestion...was able to work out the issue